# Nice problem about polynomials with nonnegative integer coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

Problem: Alice chooses a secret polynomial $p(x)$ with nonnegative integer coefficients. Bob wants to discover this polynomial by querying Alice for the value of $p(x)$ for some integer $x$ of Bob’s choice. What is the minimal number of queries Bob needs to determine $p(x)$ exactly?

I got this problem from https://jeremykun.com/2014/11/18/learning-a-single-variable-polynomial-or-the-power-of-adaptive-queries/ [the answer is here, so, if you want to think about the problem, you should be careful :) ]

Comment: Hi: I could be wrong, but your post is reminiscent of something that would get posted at puzzling.stackexchange, that is, you are asking a question you already know the answer to, and you don't have any question about it, you are just "sharing". We don't do that style of post (at least, not currently.) Do you actually have an actionable question about the probelm or solution?

Comment: No, I don't have any questions. I just found that problem interesting and wanted do share with you, guys! I'm sorry if you do not do that kind of things here. I'll post at puzzling.stackexchange . Thank you very much :)

Comment: Note something wrong in that post though: the author says that, due to polynomial interpolation, a "declarative" (as opposed to an "adaptive") query would require at least $\deg(p)+1$ trials. That is not at all obvious, since we have the additional information that all coefficients are NON-NEGATIVE. There is nothing about that in the "polynomial interpolation" thing; this additional bit of information may help limit the number of trials needed in a declarative query, just as it does in an adaptive one.

Comment: @mathguy The point, I think, is that for any $n$ integers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ there are two distinct polynomials of degree $n$ with nonnegative integer coefficients that agree at all $x_j$.  Namely, if $P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n  (x - x_i)$ you can take $Q$ and $Q + P$ where $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with integer coefficients large enough that all coefficients of $Q+P$ are nonnegative.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - You are right. I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: This is posted and answered on puzzling.se [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25922/a-secret-polynomial)